# How to make a "global" component render content based on url route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I have a FAQ button that's fixed onto the bottom right corner of the screen (it's on every screen of the website), when clicked a modal pops out displaying frequent asked questions and their respective answers, I'd like the modal to display different content based on the url that the user is on.

For example: if the user is on *[www.example.com/signup](http://www.example.com/signup)* then the modal would render the content specific to the sign up process, and when the user is on *[www.example.com/shop](http://www.example.com/shop)* only the faq's related to shopping should appear. This should be taking into account the **first** part of the url params, so if a user goes to *[www.example.com/shop/294594](http://www.example.com/shop/294594)* (or any other route that stars with /shop) then the modal still displays the same content as for *[www.example.com/shop](http://www.example.com/shop)*.

Is there any good way to to this with react-router (or any other alternative)? I did some research into react-router useParams hook but I'm not sure if it's the go-to solution since I'm just a beginner in routing. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you'de want to use useRouteMatch to read the URL path https://css-tricks.com/the-hooks-of-react-router/#useroutematch as opposed to useParams which is used to read the query parameters that appear after the question mark in the url.

Comment: I think you can accomplish that with react-router [<Route>](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route)

Comment: You can also use the `<Switch>` component to render different route-based content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `FAQ` component like this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-tgh8c?file=/components/FAQ.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const SignupFaq = () => <p>Sign up questions</p>;
const ShopFaq = () => <p>Shop questions</p>;

const faqs = {
  signup: {
    component: <SignupFaq />
  },
  shop: {
    component: <ShopFaq />
  }
};

function FAQ() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const { component } = faqs[pathname.split("/")[1]];

  const [modal, showModal] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={() => showModal(!modal)}>FAQ</button>
      <div className="modal">{modal && <div>{component}</div>}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default FAQ;
```

Comment: Thank you! To take into account the "default" route if none was found I created a default key in the faqs object and did `const { component } = faqs[pathname.split("/")[1]] ? faqs[pathname.split("/")[1]] : faqs.default;` (of course it'd be better to have `faqs[pathname.split("/")[1]] ` defined in a const so is more readable). Your solution works perfectly as expected using useLotation() with react-router.